# exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

During Automation testing with selenium (C# Chrome WebDriver), I keep on getting the following error:

**OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:62856/session/1414381932731debf24d49572cafd7b6/url. The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was: Unable to connect to the remote server  ----> System.Net.WebException : Unable to connect to the remote server  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:62856**

I tried the following:
1.  Adding the following arguments to ChromeDriver Options:

```
      options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
      options.AddArgument("proxy-server='direct://'");
      options.AddArgument("proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

2. Close all Chrome and ChromeDriver Processes prior to each run
3. Removing Anti-Virus from my computer

After all this, I am still left with this error.

Thanks,